# Id of the clicked event from html tag in lightning component

Tags: lightning, aura, event, component

I am using ondblclick event in html div tag and in controllerside am trying to get the id of the clicked event but it giving error,Below is sample code

**component.cmp**

```
<div id="{!Opp.Id + '__Budget'}" ondblclick="{!c.editBudget}">
    <ui:outputCurrency value="{!Opp.Budget__c/1000}" format="$#,##0k"/>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
editBudget : function(component, event, helper) {
    var whichOne = event.getSource();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do like below:-

```
editBudget : function(component, event, helper) {
    var whichOne = event.target.id;
}
```

> event.target.id gives you the id defined in the div. Basically, For
>   events fired by standard HTML elements, you can use
>   **event.currentTarget** and **event.target**. For events fired by base Lightning components, use **event.getSource()** instead.

Read here:- [Event Handling in Base Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm)

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this one . might be this one helpful for you

```
editBudget : function(component, event, helper) {
    var whichOne = event.getSource().getLocalId();
}
```

Comment: I am getting error event.getSource() is not an function